# What are some examples of algorithms and/or data structures are difficult or impossible to implement correctly without garbage collection?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, garbage-collection

I've heard it mentioned in very general terms that such things exist, but the details are rarely discussed.  What are your favourites?  What makes it difficult?

Comment: Do Lisp interpreters qualify as algorithms?

Comment: Ask a bog-standard CS student and they will tell you all of them.

Comment: @lars: What part of those huge programs specifically?

Comment: @delnan: let's say a metacircular version of `eval`.

Comment: I like larsmans' idea. Those functional things are hard (but not impossible) to implement without GC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard implementation of many lock-free structures like a concurrent hash table often are nearly impossible to write without a garbage collector.  These structures work by storing long linked lists of elements, then changing the heads of the lists whenever a new value is added or removed.  That way, one thread can make a change to the structure so that new threads see the change (they traverse a new linked list) while older threads continue reading older linked lists.  It's crucial that the memory be reclaimed by a garbage collector, since otherwise the thread that changed the linked list would have to somehow clean up the list it just replaced, but that list is in use by other threads,  this either leads to data races or requires the use of locks, both of which are bad.

A similar argument can be made for multithreaded lock free binary search trees, which use a related trick.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of example I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Anything is possible without GC, because computer hardware works without GC and it computes all algorithms. :-) But sometimes it is easier to implement a local GC and use it instead of writing a huge complicated code to do the same without GC. In real-world scenarions, algorithms using GC are often much simpler than their non-GC counterparts.

Anything which generates a lot of temporal data/variables is a big problem (i.e. difficult, not technically impossible) without some sort of garbage collection. For example imagine a web server with php or asp.net support where the engine of php/c# scripts has no garbage collection. Each web request from a browser creates a lot of temporal data on web server and if you had just a small memory leak in a script on server, the whole web server ends in a horrible death...

I mean if many people put scripts or plugins to server, there can be memory leaks. These scenarios require some sort of garbage collection.

Also LINQ in C# creates a lot of temporal objects. It would be paint to use it without garbage collection.

Comment: You don't have to paint the dystopian scenario for me, I'm looking for specific examples. :)

Comment: Alex, you cannot request simple examples. GC is not needed in simple cases.

Comment: If you are looking for, in strict terms an "algorithm", then such an example doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I conjecture that you mean **concurrent** data structures. If so, a lot of lockfree algorithms require Garbage Collection (or deferred/safe memory reclamation). And the most simplest example is classical lock-free stack:
[search Wikipedia by "ABA problem" - the site prohibits me from posting the link]
(ABA and safe memory reclamation are closely related problems, if you solve the latter than you solve the former too)
Is it impossible to implement them without GC? No, it's not impossible. However, it's definitely more difficult.
One solutions is to implement limited form of GC. For example, strongly thread-safe reference counting:
http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/object-life-time-management/differential-reference-counting
Another solution is to design an algorithm around the requirement, so that it just does not require a GC. For example, some lockfree producer-consumer queues (most notable the M&S queue) do require a GC. And here is a simple an efficient queue algorithm that is especially designed around GC requirement:
http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/non-intrusive-mpsc-node-based-queue

Comment: I wasn't specifically looking for concurrent data structures, although if it turns out most members of the answer set fall into that category, that's very interesting indeed! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var v = FunctionThatAllocatesMemory2(FunctionThatAllocatesMemory1());
```

Without GC there is no way to deallocate the memory returned by `FunctionThatAllocatesMemory1()`.

Comment: It depends. Technically, you can deallocate your memory1 inside your Function2.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with algorithms. You can implement the algorithm this is part of equally well trough `var tmp = Func...1(); var v = Func...2(tmp); free(tmp);`

Comment: It most certainly does have something to do with algorithms, as is evident by the fact the proposed "solutions" are mutually exclusive; deallocating memory1 inside Function2 would break if you did what @delnan is suggesting. Doing what @delnan suggests would break what @Al is suggesting. Hence making it "difficult".

Comment: The solutions are mutually exclusive, yes. But there are several solutions for about every problem, some of which will be incompatible. Regardless of availability of GC. If that's difficult, then making up your mind and coding a consistent solution is difficult.